# When does Google index your Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, google

I think that by default, a new profile starts out with a [`<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html), because I can’t find my unique name when I search on Google.

Is there any minimum reputation requirement before it is indexed?

My goal is make my profile discoverable in Google when I search for my name.

Comment: Where do you see a “noindex tag”? The only other place where this is set, would be the [`robots.txt`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) which is global. What makes you think there’s a reputation threshold for indexing user profiles in search engines? Your profile is just a few hours old. Don’t you think search engines just haven’t indexed your profile yet?

Comment: @user4642212 they are talking about the “noindex” meta tag. Also see the discussion here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746. New user profiles are indeed no longer indexed by Google to block profile spammers but I don’t know what the criteria are for when you do get indexed. Not that a noindex tag is used but the restriction does exits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters _“they are talking about the ‘noindex’ meta tag”_ — Yes, I know. I fail to find one in any profile page. I probably shouldn’t have put quotes around “noindex tag”; I just wanted to quote the OP.

Comment: @user4642212 I’m assuming at this point that they found the discussion I linked to where the use of a meta tag was suggested and the OP assumed that’s how this was actually implemented.

Comment: But it will be searched as "tami k a wil kin so nt mp", not a very specific search (lots of false positives). Will it work if quoted? Also, it may or may not be detected as a domain name.

Answer (score 7):

Profiles of new users are indeed not indexed in search engines, because a [large number of spam profiles were (and still are) being created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w) for no other purpose but to catch out searches in Google for certain keywords.

This is not implemented by inserting a `robots` meta tag, however. Stack Overflow simply doesn’t include such profiles in the [site map served only to search engine crawlers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353738/stack-overflow-sitemap-xml-gives-a-404) and so Google never knows to index them.

I don’t think the exact criteria for when an account profile is actually indexed by a search engine are public, but the threshold is quite low. Likely a (proper) question or answer that receives an upvote is enough.